# (UWP) WebClient and downloading data from URL in

Tags: windows, url, asynchronous, webclient, uwp

How do you download data from an url in UWP? I'm used to using WebClient's DownloadData-method, but it can't be used anymore.

Comment: Use HttpClient instead

Comment: As @KooKiz said, use HttpClient. Here is the [sample project from Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HttpClient).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

.NET for UWP does not have the WebClient class.

But you have several alternative ways to download the data from URL in UWP.

For example:

```
    var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://www.bing.com");

    var donnetClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

    var winrtClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
```

If you want to download the data at background, you can use the [BackgroundDownloader class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader.aspx)

Comment: `HttpClient` seems better for future cross plat code. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396