# Retrieve web page content like a browser

Tags: c#, .net, web, webclient, scrapy

After I learned some things about differents technologies, I wanted to make a small project using UWP+NoSQL. I wanted to do a small UWP app that grabs the horoscope and display it on my raspberry Pi every morning.

So I took a `WebClient`, and I do the following:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
string downloadString = client.DownloadString("http://www.horoscope.com/us/horoscopes/general/horoscope-general-daily-today.aspx?sign=2");
```

But it seems that it detect that this request isn't coming from a browser, since the interesting part is not in the content(and when I check with the browser, it is in the initial HTML, according to fiddler).

I also tried with ScrapySharp but I got the same result. Any idea why?

(I've already done the UWP part, so I don't want to change the topic of my personal project just because it is detected as a "bot")

**EDIT**

It seems I wasn't clear enough. The issue is **not* that I'm unable to parse the HTML, the issue is that I don't receive expected HTML when using ScrapySharp/WebClient

**EDIT2**

Here is what I retrieve: http://pastebin.com/sXi4JJRG

And, I don't get(by example) the "Star ratings by domain" + the related images for each stars

Comment: I tried to find that XML, however I couldn't. Can you explain a bit where is it?

Comment: @ganchito55 sorry, I meant the initial HTML, not XML. I was just saying that it isn't loaded within an ajax call

Comment: Have you tried HTML agility pack??

Comment: What part specifically you want? Can you shared a pastebin or something like this with the part of that web that you want?

Comment: @Reddy For what I'm aware, Html Agility Pack is only for the parsing no?

Comment: @ganchito55 I'm trying to retrieve the part with the image. It is contained in the HTML I receive when I'm using chrome, but I don't receive it when I retrieve the web page with `ScrapySharp`/ `WebClient`

Comment: Which image exactly are you missing? It seems most images are there when querying with .NET.

Comment: @Evk  I added what I retrieved with the previous code, and a concrete example of a text that is not present in the retrieved page.

Comment: Cannot reproduce that with exact code you provided. I receive full content every time, including "Star ratings by domain" and other stuff.

Comment: Hi @J4N, I've made requst with Fiddler and WebClient. In Both cases I recieve all HTML result like a normal browser. Only images (naturally) are missed. What exactly do you want, and instead do not have?

Comment: can anyone help with this question?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52516038/c-sharp-know-the-height-of-html-content-in-a-console-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I know what's going on: I compared the real output (no fancy user agent strings) to the output as supplied by your pastebin and found something interesting. On line 213, your pastebin has:

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="/us/profiles/zodiac/index-profile-zodiac-sign.aspx" class="dropdown-toggle" data-hov...ck">Forecast Tarot Readings</div>
```

Mind the `data-hov...ck` near the end. In the real output, this was:

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="/us/profiles/zodiac/index-profile-zodiac-sign.aspx" class="dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="link">Astrology</a>
```

followed by about 600 lines of code, including the aforementioned 'interesting part'. On line 814, it says:

```
<div class="bot-explore-col-subtitle f14 blocksubtitle black">Forecast Tarot Readings</div>
```

which, starting with the ck in black, matches up with the rest of the pastebin output. So, either pastebin has condensed the output or the original output was.

I created a new console application, inserted your code, and got the result I expected, including the 600 lines of html you seem to miss:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
    string downloadString = client.DownloadString("http://www.horoscope.com/us/horoscopes/general/horoscope-general-daily-today.aspx?sign=2");

    File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Temp\source-mywebclient.html", downloadString);
}
```

My `WebClient` is from `System.Net`. And changing the UserAgent hardly has any effect, a couple of links are a bit different.

So, to sum it up: Your problem has nothing to do with content that is inserted dynamically after the initial get, but possibly with webclient combined with UWP. There's another question regarding webclient and UWP on the site: [(UWP) WebClient and downloading data from URL in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123082/uwp-webclient-and-downloading-data-from-url-in) that states you should use HttpClient. Maybe that's a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the entire content of the web page using the code snippet shown below:

```
internal static string ReadText(string Url, int TimeOutSec)
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpClient _client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeOutSec) })
        {
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html"));
            using (HttpResponseMessage _responseMsg = _client.GetAsync(Url))
            {
                using (HttpContent content = _responseMsg.Content)
                {
                    return content.ReadAsString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch { throw; }
}
```

Or in a simple way:

```
public static void DownloadString (string address)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient ();
    string reply = client.DownloadString (address);

    Console.WriteLine (reply);
}
```

(re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Already did this, the issue is that I don't get the same HTML content that when asking with a browser. The server seems to detect that I'm asking with an application and returns me only the structure of the website without the interessting content

Answer (score 1):

yes, WebClient won't give you expected result. many sites have scripts to load content. so to emulate browser you also should run page scripts.
I have never did similar things, so my answer pure theoretical.

To solve the problem you need "headless browser".
I know two project for this (I have never try ony of it):

http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/ - it seems to be outdated

http://www.awesomium.com/

Comment: But like I mentionned, the content was present in the initial HTML file that I  got within fiddler, so it hasn't been loaded within an ajax call

Comment: That strange. Just tried your code and got HTML with horoscope. I can assume, you may be banned for many request during testing

Comment: I just tested from another network, another computer, and I got the same result. I posted the result within a pastebin link(in my main question). Are you sure you got the interessting part and not just some HTML?

Comment: sorry, was away from computer for last days. check out code I recieved with your code. http://pastebin.com/8cWe15hk

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I used http://www.nrecosite.com/phantomjs_wrapper_net.aspx it worked well, and as Anton mentioned it is a headless browser. Maybe it will be some help.

Comment: Do you have any example how to open a page? I guess it's in the PhantomJS part, but I cannot find an example

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if all the 'interesting part' you expect to see 'in the content' are images? You are aware of the fact you have to retrieve any images separately? The fact that a html page contains `<image.../>` tags does not magically display them as well. As you can see with Fiddler, after retrieving a page, the browser then retrieves all images, style sheets, javascript and all other items that are specified, but not included in the page. (you might need to clear the browser cache to see this happen...)

Comment: I'm quite aware of the html. I'm expecting to get the image element and check their URL to define what was the rating. As I shown in the pastebin in the question, it seems there is only the template of the website(header, menu, footer) but not that much content